# .Net core web api - Role based authorization (Allow specific domains without asking JWT)

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, jwt, roles

I have an API that uses standard role based authorization and JWT. I need to allow specific domains to use the API without providing JWT while still continue to using role based auth for other users. Is there a way to do this? Can I assign roles to these domains if such a way exists?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an authorization filter. When authorization is required, the filter is executed. In the filter you can validate the domain an set the current user, including the roles(s):

```
//using System;
//using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Security.Claims;
//using System.Security.Principal;
//using System.Web;
//using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
//using System.Web.Http.Filters;

public class AddIdentityFilter : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var allowedIpAdresses = new List<string> { "127.0.0.1", "" };
        // Replace with your code to test the domain
        var isInDomain = allowedIpAdresses.Contains(GetIp());
        var identity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;

        if (!identity.IsAuthenticated && isInDomain)
        {
            // Add the roles to the new Identity
            HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("DomainUser"), new[] { "Admin" });
        }
        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
    }

    // Helper to determine the ipaddress
    private string GetIp()
    {
        var context = (HttpContextBase)HttpContext.Current.Items["MS_HttpContext"];
        if (context != null)
            return context.Request.UserHostAddress;

        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            return HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

        return null;
    }

}
```

In WebApiConfig.cs add the filter:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Only needed for Owin
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();

        config.Filters.Add(new AddIdentityFilter());

        // ...
    }
}
```